# Popup image in Bootsrap Carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-image-gallery

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have the image popup if the user clicks on the image in the carousel. How can it be done?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" >
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php foreach ($repairPics as $ind => $pics) {  ?>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $ind;?>" <?php echo (($ind == 0) ? 'class="active"' : '');?>></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin-left: 10%;height: 100%;">

        <?php foreach ($repairPics as $ind => $pics) {  ?>
                <div class="item <?php echo (($ind == 0) ? 'active' : '');?>" style="height: 100%;">
                    <img style="height: 100%;" class="d-inline-block w-100" src="https://earthsky.org/upl/2017/06/Interplanetary-Transport-System-SpaceX-Elon-Musk-300x158.jpg" alt="Starship">
                </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="left: -1%">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="right: 0%;">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extension such as [Featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/), which is a very lightweight jQuery lightbox.

I created [a fiddle (click here)](https://jsfiddle.net/ynf63edc/10/) and added featherlight as a resource and modified your code slightly to work without php. Basically you put a `<a href="YOUR_HREF" data-featherlight="image">` around your images, which will make your images clickable and showing on a popup.

*Hint: Please note that the lightbox will only be as large as your defined image is!*

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin-left: 10%;height: 100%;">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
          <a href="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" data-featherlight="image">
              <img style="height: 100%;" class="d-inline-block w-100" src="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" alt="Starship">
           </a>
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
           <a href="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" data-featherlight="image">
              <img style="height: 100%;" class="d-inline-block w-100" src="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" alt="Starship">
           </a>
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
         <a href="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" data-featherlight="image">
              <img style="height: 100%;" class="d-inline-block w-100" src="http://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg" alt="Starship">
           </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="right: 0%;">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This result looks something like this:

[image: Example of the lightbox]

There is also an `iframe` example how to open a `100% width` and `100% height` lightbox, which you will find in [this section](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#open-youtube-video-with-featherlight).

Good luck! I hope that this will answer your question.